# .AddNew vba equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, vba

**Is the AddNew function VBA similar to Insert into clause c#?**

**VBA**

```
Set RsTrt = New ADODB.Recordset
RsTrt.Open "Select  * from TblSysRecordTrt ORDER BY trtName,Trtdate DESC", aaDbConnect(), adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
      Function AddTrt(StrName As String, strdesc As String, DtTrt As Date, StrUser As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrAdd
    With RsTrt
        .AddNew
            .Fields("trtName") = StrName
            .Fields("trtDesc") = strdesc
            .Fields("TrtDate") = DtTrt
            .Fields("TrtUser") = aaUser()


        .Update
    End With
        AddTrt = True
    FinAdd:
        Exit Function
    ErrAdd:

        AddTrt = False
        Resume FinAdd
    End Function
```

**C#**

```
public static bool AddTrt(string StrName, string strdesc,DateTime DtTrt , string StrUser)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "similar to" in that the end result is the same. It is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677536(v=vs.85).aspx

When using `AddNew` with an updatable `RecordSet` and then calling `Update` causes the ADODB object to send an INSERT command back to the server - so it's just a way of abstracting-away raw SQL statements in your code.

There is a similar approach in C#/.NET, but the `ADODB.RecordSet` class is obsolete - the nearest analogue is `System.Data.DataTable` and `DataSet`, and the latest wisdom is to use Entity Framework instead of the weakly-typed `DataTable` class.